# Picasso with recyclerview auto rotates some images

Tags: android

I'm having issues with Picasso displaying some pictures in the wrong orientation and others in the right one. I have this one rotated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zhTi.jpg . I've seen threads like this one: [Picasso displays in wrong orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330171/picasso-displays-in-wrong-orientation) and this one: [Why image auto rotate when set to Imageview with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411409/why-image-auto-rotate-when-set-to-imageview-with-picasso/42411772) where it's recommended to either use Compressor from https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor or to manually rotate it.

I was hoping for one that just undoes the weird rotation for a standard recycler view carousel experience pulling from uris. I'd also be open to techniques to keep it uniform such as to crop the images in a recyclerview to deal with the potential issue of the proportions causing this: [Android ImageView Displaying Rotated Images Although Source Is Not Rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929474/android-imageview-displaying-rotated-images-although-source-is-not-rotated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a problem like this, and I solved it with the Glide library.

```
dependencies {

      implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
      annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
 }
```

and just

```
 GlideApp.with(context)
         .load("http://via.url.com/300.png")
         .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
         .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
         .into(ivImg);
```

Comment: thank you! I just needed to change `GlideApp` to `Glide`